# Validate input fields on bootstrap modal window button clicks using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to validate input fields on submit/ok button click in a modal window using angularjs framework. What I have tried are to add the attributes required/ng-required on my input button. But on my ok button click the input text field is not validated and the modal window is dismissed. As below is my modal-body. I would like to see the angular behaviour of showing the red border around it on click of ok.

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
      <input type="text" class="input-box" size="10" required ng-model="data.myNumber"/>
</div>
```

Is there something additional I need to do in my event handler for submit buttons? Below is a plunker I created for the demo. Any help would be highly appreciated.
    http://plnkr.co/edit/ACoTQgIVnWnR92LngT89?p=preview
By the way the plunker will run only in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to use the correct elements and corresponding classnames. You'll need to wrap your input in a `div` with classname `form-group`, and that needs to be wrapped into a `form` element. The actual `input` needs to have the `form-control` class:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required/>
  </div>
</form>
```

A nice read on properly using forms with bootstrap can be found here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Now that it's a proper bootstrap form you can add angular validation. That's very simple just by giving the form and the input a name attribute:

```
<form name="modalForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="modalInput" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now angular will preform validation in the background. It will add `modalForm` to the scope of your modalcontroller from where you can get the state of the form and it's input elements.

Now because of the `required` attribute the input and form has been deemed invalid which can be checked by using: `modalForm.modalInput.$invalid` That will return true, when the input is empty . You can use it to add the `has-error` class to the `form-group` div element which will turn the border of the input element to red. You can dynamicly add this class by using the `ng-class` directive:

```
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': modalForm.modalInput.$invalid }" >
    <input name="modalInput" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required/>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can also add a message which also will be colored through the `has-error` class. Add a `span` element with the `help-block` class and use the `ng-show` directive to toggle it on the required error:

```
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': modalForm.modalInput.$invalid }" >
    <input name="modalInput" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required/>
    <span ng-show="modalForm.modalInput.$error.required" class="help-block">Input is required.</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now if you want to make it impossible to push the `ok` button when the form is invalid you can toggle the `disabled` class and/or add use the `ng-disabled` directive:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="modalForm.$invalid" ng-class="{ 'disabled': modalForm.$invalid }" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
```

I recommend reading the previous link on bootstrap forms and the following guide for using angular's forms. It has good examples:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Here's the complete modal code and a working example on Plunker:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">My Modal</h3>
  </div>
  <form name="modalForm">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': modalForm.modalInput.$invalid }" >
        <input name="modalInput" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required/>
        <span ng-show="modalForm.modalInput.$error.required" class="help-block">Input is required.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="modalForm.$invalid" ng-class="{ 'disabled': modalForm.$invalid }" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GUE3sGci478obwOrzhNw?p=preview

PS: i know it doesn't answer you question as to how to preform input validation on button click but that's because it's not "the angular way" of using forms. The above and the links i provide should give you a good idea on how to properly use validation within Angular. Hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the main directions to get what you want:

- Wrap your `input` in a `<form>` element.
- In the `ok()` function, close modal only if it's *valid*

I also replaced `type="text"` with `type="number"`, since you want the user to input a number. Also corrected the plunker to make it work:

**ModalInstanceController**

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance){
  $scope.ok = function () {
    if ($scope.numberForm.$valid) {
      $modalInstance.close();
    }
  };
  // ...
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="numberForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control input-box" required ng-model="data.myNumber"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" >OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

See **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ILdc0g9ZPRUCHg3qcVrq?p=preview)**

---

Improvement: **Play with angular validation to add *red borders* if input is invalid:**

```
<form name="numberForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : numberForm.myNum.$invalid }">
        <input type="number" name="myNum" class="form-control input-box" required ng-model="data.myNumber"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-disabled="numberForm.$invalid">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

See **[forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n4qUhLmkJ5dnAFWdKCgO?p=preview)**